# Is Material UI library affecting on Google caching of web page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, next.js, material-ui

Is Material UI library affecting on Google caching of web page?

I have this question because one of my project I have used material in whole project.At the time caching Google crawler cache everything except that component where I used material UI useTheme so here is my question that useTheme is impacting on caching.

Comment: I think Material UI doesn't affect Google's caching of a web page.

Comment: It might be affects by useTheme of Material UI @LightningMcQueen

Comment: Documentation? Source?